Thunderbird: Stop adding my local IP address to the message header
Can I stop IMAP servers from adding my PC's private IP address to the mail header in Received: from []?
Is there a setting of Thunderbird 115.10.1?
PC ---> CPE ---> CGNAT ---> Internet

Thank you for looking up the solution. Sadly, I neither can I vote up user45475's answer nor comment on answer with a solution due to my account's lack of reputation.
